# Calling next previous iDangero.us when there are multiple instances of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [idangero.us](http://www.idangero.us/) slider. I have multiple sliders on my page. I have a requirement to a add a  next/previous buttons to the slider. Here is my current implementation. The issue with below is that the click events call all sliders on the page.  What is the best method to use the swipePrev and swipeNext functions when there are multiple instances.

```
    $('.swiper-container').each(function () {

    var prevNext = "<a class='arrow-left' href='#'></a><a class='arrow-right' href='#'></a>"; 
    var config = {
      mode: 'horizontal',
      calculateHeight: true,
      initialSlide: 0,
      visibilityFullFit: true
    };

    if ($(this).find('.swiper-wrapper').children().length > 1) {
      $(this).prepend(prevNext);
      var $pager = $('<div class="pagination" />').appendTo(this);
      config.pagination = $pager[0];
      config.paginationClickable = true;
    }

    var swiper = $(this).swiper(config);

    $('.arrow-left').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swiper.swipePrev();
    });

    $('.arrow-right').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swiper.swipeNext();
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create multiple instances of block like this

```
<div class="device">
<a class="arrow-left" href="#"></a> 
<a class="arrow-right" href="#"></a>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="img/slider1-1.png"> </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="img/slider1-2.png"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

And use this js with objects array and nice `find()` selector.

```js
var swipes = []
$('.swiper-container').each(function(i, obj) {
swipes[i] = new Swiper(obj);

$(this).parent().find('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  swipes[i].swipePrev()

})    

$(this).parent().find('.arrow-right').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  swipes[i].swipeNext()    
})  


});
```

Comment: This works great.  However for those using v2.5.0 like I am a small adjustment is needed when instantiating a new Swiper instance. Switch out `swipes[i] = new Swiper(obj);` with **`swipes[i] = $(obj).swiper(opts);`**.  `opts` would then be an object of configurations if you have any.  For example `var opts = {eventTarget: 'container', mode: 'vertical'}`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    var swiper = [];

    $('.swiper-container').each(function(index){

        var $el = $(this);

        swiper[index] = $el.swiper({
            //Your options here:
            mode:'horizontal',
            pagination: $el.find('.swiper-pagination')[0],
            ... more settings here
        });

        $el.find('.prev-slide').on('click', function(){
            swiper[index].swipePrev();
        });

        $el.find('.next-slide').on('click', function(){
            swiper[index].swipeNext();
        });

    });
```

Comment: it's a bad idea. 
`
$(document).on('click', '.prev-slide', function(){
        var pSwiper = $(this).parents('.swiper-container')[0].swiper;
        pSwiper.slideNext();
        return false;
    });
`
The same for `.next-slide`